# Issue in rendering circles in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make tooltip like: http://jsfiddle.net/6cJ5c/10/ for my graph and that is the result on my realtime graph: http://jsfiddle.net/QBDGB/52/  I am wondering why there is a gap between the circles and the graph and why at the beginning there is a vertical line of circles? When it starts the circles are close to the curve but suddendly they start to jump up and down !! I want the circles to move smooothly and stick on the surface of the curve. I think the problem is that they are not moving with the "path1" and so it does not recognize the circles and thats why they are moving separetly or maybe the value of tooltipis are different of the value of the curve so they do not overlap!. That is how the data is generated ( value and time) and the tooltip:

```css
var data1 = initialise();  
var data1s = data1;

 function initialise() {

 var arr = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     var obj = {
 time: Date.now(),
 value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90)
  };
     arr.push(obj);
 }
 return arr;
}

 // push a new element on to the given array
function updateData(a) {
 var obj = {
 time: Date.now(),
 value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 90)
  };
 a.push(obj);
   }


 var formatTime = d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S");

  //tooltip

  var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
   .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

   var blueCircles = svg.selectAll("dot")
    .data(data1s)
    .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", 3)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.time); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
        .style("fill", "white")
        .style("stroke", "red")
        .style("stroke-width", "2px")
        .on("mousemove", function(d ,i) {
            div.transition()
                .duration(650)
                .style("opacity", .9);
            div.html(formatTime(new Date(d.time)) + "<br/>" + d.value)
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(d ,i ) {
            div.transition()
                .duration(650)
                .style("opacity", 0);
        });
         blueCircles.data(data1s)
        .transition()
        .duration(650)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.time); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.value); });
```

Please kindly tell me your opinions since I really need it :(
As I said maybe I should add "mouseover and mouse move functions" to the "path" to make it recognize the tooltip. something like following. but I am nor really sure :(

```css
 var path1 = svg.append("g")
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
      .append("path")
      .data([data1])
      .attr("class", "line1")
       .on("mouseover", mouseover)
      .on("mousemove", mousemove)
      .on("mouseout", mouseout);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in the interpolation of your paths. You set the interpolation between points on your `var area` to "basis", which I [found](https://coderwall.com/p/thtwbw) is a B-spline interpolation. This means the area drawn *does not go through the points* in your dataset, as shown in this example:
[image]

The path your points move over, though, are just straight lines between the points in your dataset. I updated and changed the interpolation from basic to linear, to demonstrate that it will work that way. I also set the ease() for the movement to linear, which makes it less 'jumpy'. http://jsfiddle.net/QBDGB/53/

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer :) it moves much better, but when the circles reaches to (end) left of the graph they start to move not on the line. by the way is there any way to make the vertical line of circles when the graph starts? Since I expected them to be placed on the the curve but they come from from left to right of the graph.